# React Native I can not store an array with AsyncStorage

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, asyncstorage

I am newbie in React Native and I am trying to store and get an array with AsyncStorage in ReactNative.

I have two problems.

First, I do not know why but when I storage data, it only works the second time but I am calling first the set of useState.

```
const handleAddTask = () => {
    Keyboard.dismiss();
    setTaskItems([...taskItems, task]);
    storeData(taskItems);
  };
```

Second, how can I call the getData function to get all the data and show it? Are there something like .onInit, .onInitialize... in ReactNative? Here is my full code

```
const [task, setTask] = useState();
const [taskItems, setTaskItems] = useState([]);

  const handleAddTask = () => {
    Keyboard.dismiss();
    setTaskItems([...taskItems, task]);
    storeData(taskItems);
  };

  const completeTask = (index) => {
    var itemsCopy = [...taskItems];
    itemsCopy.splice(index, 1);
    setTaskItems(itemsCopy);
    storeData(taskItems);
  }

  const storeData = async (value) => {
    try {
      await AsyncStorage.setItem('@tasks', JSON.stringify(value))
      console.log('store', JSON.stringify(taskItems));
    } catch (e) {
      console.log('error');
    }
  }

  const getData = async () => {
    try {
      const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@tasks')
      if(value !== null) {
        console.log('get', JSON.parse(value));
      } 
    } catch(e) {
      console.log('error get');
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating state in React is not super intuitive. It's not asynchronous, and can't be awaited. However, it's not done immediately, either - it gets put into a queue which React optimizes according to its own spec.

That's why BYIRINGIRO Emmanuel's answer is correct, and is the easiest way to work with state inside functions. If you have a state update you need to pass to more than one place, set it to a variable inside your function, and use that.

If you need to react to state updates inside your component, use the `useEffect` hook, and add the state variable to its dependency array. The function in your useEffect will then run whenever the state variable changes.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, now I need to get data at the "init" of the app.

Comment: It seems to me that you want the data on the initialization of the component, and not the app.  You can use `useEffect` to run your methods on mount of the component.  In your case this would look something like `useEffect(() => AsyncStorage.getItem('@tasks').then(data => setTaskItems(JSON.parse(data)), [setTaskItems]);`  [Here are the docs for useEffect.](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) If you want it at the init of the app, you can call it in App.jsx or even index.js.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you're update state `setTaskItems([...taskItems, task])` before save new data in local storage, `storeData(taskItems)` executed before state updated and save old state data.

Refactor `handleAddTask` as below.

```js
  const handleAddTask = () => {
   Keyboard.dismiss();

const newTaskItems = [...taskItems, task]
    setTaskItems(newTaskItems);
    storeData(newTaskItems);
  };
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, now I can store data correctly, but do you know how can I solve the other problem? I want to get the data in the storage at the first to be able to show it when app starts.

Comment: Glad to hear that @Tomas. Can you approve this answer for future readers' reference.

Comment: For other problems, I offer 1:1 personal support service. You can reach me at emmbyiringiro@gmail.com

Comment: I will approve the answer when I had both problems solved.