# State in useEffect undefined after the useEffect sets the state?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a React Native app in which I am running some code that looks like the code below. Why is the following output `undefined`? Reading `someState` from `useEffect` is `undefined` even when the state is set inside the `useEffect`

```
const SomeComponent = () => {
  const [someState,setSomeState] = useState();
  
  const anFunction = () => {
    let data = 'data'
    return data
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const theData = anFunction();
    setSomeState(theData)
    console.log(someState)
  },[])

  ...

  // later renders some component
}
```

I am attempting set the state and then read the state within this `useEffect` because I would like to implement something like:

```
  const doSomethingWithTheState = () => {
    //some transformation here
    setSomeState(transformedData)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const theData = anFunction();
    setSomeState(theData)
    
    doSomethingWithTheState()

  },[])
```

Comment: Calling `setSomeState` triggers a state update, but you don't see the updated state until the next re-render of the component. If you want some action to trigger whenever `someState` changes, you should put it in a separate `useEffect` with `someState` in the dependency array.

Comment: State updates in `useEffect` are not synchronous, and your `console.log` is referencing the current state and not the updated state. Please see this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/the-usestate-set-method-is-not-reflecting-a-change-immediately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might get something out of my answer to a similar question: [React Native I can not store an array with AsyncStorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71071621/react-native-i-can-not-store-an-array-with-asyncstorage/71075387#71075387)

@gloo posted a much more interesting discussion on this issue here: [The useState set method is not reflecting a change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/the-usestate-set-method-is-not-reflecting-a-change-immediately)

Setting state is neither sync nor async. It's a quirk/feature of the React ecosystem. State is immutable in terms of a single render; therefore you'll never get the updated state until the next render.

If you need to work with the state directly after it's been changed, do it in a useEffect with the state variable in the dependency array.

Comment: between your answer and gloos answer I was able to piece together a solution to having the state available for the `useEffect` function. Kind of annoying behavior on the part of React but very interesting nonetheless.

Comment: I edited @gloo's link into my answer because I feel it is a much more interesting and complete discussion of the issue.  I'll be linking that from now on.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It should work by adding a .then

```
.then(doSomethingWithTheState())
```

Answer (score 0):

It is undefined because `useEffect` is not `async`. Your initial state is already `undefined` so you see `undefined` in `console.log`. To create async logic inside `useEffect` you should update like this

```
useEffect(() => {
    async function test(){
      //Your logic here
    } 
    test()

  },[])
```

Answer (score 0):

Because my goal is to mutate the data within the `useEffect` it was better to initialize my state using the `anFunction()` (obviously this is still just an example). Here's what my code looks like now:

```
const SomeComponent = () => {
  const [someState,setSomeState] = useState(anFunction());
  
  const anFunction = () => {
    let data = 'data'
    return data
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(someState)
  },[])

  ...

  // later renders some component
}
```

I've seen of conversation about how useState is async. This is misleading. Looking at Abe's answer and his description will guide you towards resolving many weird React state-setting behaviors.

Do not try to `await` or `async` your state setting within the `useEffect`.